# SQL Server trigger for creating Alphanumeric value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I understand that other similar questions have already been posted and answered on SO but I haven't found anything that actually addresses my need. Just so you know, I know how to write basic SQL queries but I've never worked with triggers or stored procedures before - I'm learning as I go.

So, the goal is to create a trigger that generates an alphanumeric value in SQL Server whenever a record is inserted. I used the following script to create my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [ISSUES]
(
    [IssueId] int identity(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [IssueIdProxy] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

When the said trigger kicks in, it is supposed to insert the alphanumeric value to the `IssueIdProxy` column in the following format: `ABC-00001`, `ABC-00002`, ..., `ABC-00015`, and so on. As you can see, the non-numeric part (i.e., "ABC") stays the same; it is only the numeric part that gets incremented by one for the next record. As for the trigger script, I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER alphaNumericKey
ON ISSUES
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE a
    SET IssueIdProxy = 'ABC' + LEFT('0000' + CAST(inserted.IssueId AS VARCHAR(10)), 5)
    FROM ISSUES a
    INNER JOIN inserted ON a.IssueId = inserted.IssueId
END
```

My challenge is to keep the numeric part of the value to be always six-digit long. I need to know how to control the number of leading zeros depending on the number of digits that are generated from the `IssueId` as the record size grows. Also, please feel free to correct me if any part of the trigger script doesn't make sense or is wrong.

Comment: try use LEFT(LPAD( CAST(inserted.IssueId AS VARCHAR(10),5), '0'),5);

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE - I got an error message that says 'LPAD' is not a recognized built-in function name. Is that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: is it mysql you are using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: try: LEFT(FORMAT(CAST(inserted.IssueId AS VARCHAR(10)), '00000'),5)

Comment: Now I get, "Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function"

Comment: sorry forgot Format cant take a varchar and i dont think LEFT can take an int.. try: LEFT(CAST(FORMAT(inserted.IssueId,'00000') AS VARCHAR(10)),5)

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE - The script compiled and ran successfully. But, shouldn't the trigger now automatically kick in to insert the alphanumeric value to the IssueIdProxy column? When I tried to manually insert a record, I got an error that says NULL value cannot be inserted to IssueIdProxy column. But I thought the trigger was supposed to take care of that.

Comment: the trigger only runs after the initial insert. Because you have the proxy field as not null you are going to get an error if you try to insert without specifying a proxy value. This value should be overwritten after the insert. Remove the not null attribute from the proxy field, insert an arbitrary value to proxy column on each insert or change after to Instead of insert and pass the issueid in trigger aswell. Easiest option is remove the not null from the proxy field.. It's always going to be populated by the trigger anyway

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE - Works wonderfully. Would you quickly copy and paste your comments in a separate reply so that I can give you the full credit you deserve? Thanks!

Comment: It would usually make sense to make this a computed column rather than using a trigger to maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be.

```
SET IssueIdProxy=CONCAT('ABC',FORMAT(inserted.IssueId,'0000'))
```

The format command will pad any empty fields in the IssueId with the String passed to it. In our case '0000' four zeros. It will return a nvarchar. Concat will add this to the 'ABC'.

The trigger only runs after the initial insert has completed. Because you have the proxy field as not null you are going to get an error if you try to insert without specifying a proxy value an error will be thrown.

To avoid this you could:

1: Remove not null from the proxy field. - You run the risk of null values appearing here if an update command is used. Unless you create an update trigger that does the same as above. You could add default 0 to the proxy field so even if null is set a default value of 0 appears and prevents errors.

2: Keep null and insert arbitary value to proxy field. This will be overwritten by the trigger after the insert completes.

3: Change your trigger to INSTEAD OF INSERT. This means your insert command will be ignored completely and just the trigger will run on insert. To use this you would have to update your trigger to set the Issue field aswell.